transmission bake only works on original model
The transmission bake works on my original models eyes so the texture itself is fine and I've tested settings in the materials tab and they match for both materials. I've also tried swapping between both UV sets and it doesn't fix it either.
Original Model

Baked Model

It's the same texture into the same socket with the same UVs with the same material settings so I'm a bit lost.
